# useEffect blocking the ui update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export const UseState = () => { 
    const [count , setCount] = useState(0)
    useEffect(()=>{
        let y=1;
        for (let i=0;i<500000000;i++){
            y=y+1;
        }
    },[count]);
    
    return (
        
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>setCount(c => c+1)}> Count - {count}</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have read that useEffect run after the ui get updated but when I mount or update the count state it take time to get update in ui. Does doing synchronous heavy task in useEffect  block the ui ?

Comment: Even if it runs after the React UI updates are *calculated*, it's still running before the browser can *render* the UI.  What you're running is a long-running blocking operation.  Taking a step back... Why?  What is the goal of this operation?  You've successfully demonstrated that JavaScript is single-threaded and that the browser doesn't render until the thread completes.  This is known and expected behavior and has nothing to do with React.  But what's the goal here?  What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I was testing when useEffect run. I initially thought that it run after browser UI are updated . You are saying it run before browser  renders the Ui . You Clear my doubt.